# How do I set y axis limits and breaks, and choose symbols in multiple variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

```
df<-age_limbset
df$limbset<-as.factor(df$limbset)
limb_splot<-ggplot(df, aes(x=age,y=score))
limb_splot +
  geom_point(aes(color = limbset, shape = limbset))+
  geom_smooth(aes(color = limbset),
              method = loess, se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","hotpink"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","hotpink"))+
  ggpubr::stat_cor(aes(color = limbset),method="spearman", label.x = 3)+
  labs(x="Age (years)",y="Total proprioception score (0-4)")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,4,0.5))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2,16,2))+
  theme_bw()
```

Sorry I do not know how to enter data here.
I have created this scatterplot showing relationship between age and proprioception of both forelimbs and hindlimbs. The plot is listening to my instruction for the x axis limits and breaks, but I can only get it to listen to either the limits OR the breaks for the y axis. What am I doing wrong?
How can I change the symbols for the data points? Ideally I would like them all to be dots.
I would also like to change the legend name and labels to start with a capital letter.

[image: scatterplot]

Comment: See [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for suggestions for including data so we can actually run and test the code.

Comment: Difficult to help when you don't show the code that is failing (i.e. the axis limits). But make sure you define the limits in the scales you are already using, so use e.g. `scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,4,0.5), limits = c(0, 1))`, not `scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,4,0.5)) + ylim(0, 1)`. To change the symbols, see `?scale_shape_manual`.

Comment: If you don't want different shapes, you need to remove the `shapes = limbset` from your aesthetics. (Please limit to 1 question per post)

Comment: I do apologise @Axeman , please understand I am new to this forum AND RStudio hence my struggles! I am reading the article from MrFlick on how to add this but it is all alien language to me I'm afraid

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a reproducible example which also addresses your questions, e.g. with `scale_shape_manual` to get the shapes you want which you could choose [here](https://r-graphics.org/recipe-scatter-shapes).

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(years = rep(seq(2, 16, 1), 2),
       score = abs(rnorm(30, 10, 10)),
       set = rep(c("fore", "hind"), 15)
) |> 
  ggplot(aes(years, score, shape = set, colour = set)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40), breaks = seq(0, 40, 5)) +
  labs(x = "Years", y = "Score", shape = "Set", colour = "Set")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>